# How to Compare TimeSpan entered with TimeSpan from Database

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two times I received from the database in class TimeSpan

```
begTime = current.data('bgtime');
                    endTime = current.data('endtime');
```

I am comparing them to two times entered by user

```
 $('#timeToStart').on('change', function () {
            var startTime = $('#timeToStart').val();
            sTimeHire = startTime;


        });
        $('#timeToEnd').on('change', function () {
            var endTime = $('#timeToEnd').val();
            eTimeHire = endTime;
       });


if (begTime > sTimeHire || endTime < eTimeHire) {
                        alert("yayy it works");

                    }
```

For some reason if sTimeHire and begTime are both 7:00pm it goes into the if statement even though it should only go in if begTime is greater?

However if I experiment with endTime separately  it works and if endTime and eTimeHire are both 9:00 PM it does not go into the if statement.

I noticed that begTime does not have any seconds attached when I do
        `alert(begTime)`

is it possible that it's considered more than the 07:00:00 of sTimeHire because of that?

Comment: Convert your times to a unix timestamp, then you will be comparing integers. From there you can convert back to whatever format you desire.

Comment: What strings are you getting from `current.data('bgTime')` and what values are users able to enter into `timeToStart`? Because `TimeSpan` is a .NET struct, which simply represents an amount of time (i.e., 5 hours, 30 minutes, 32 seconds), not a specific time (i.e. 5:30:32 am).

Answer (score 0):

You are using JavaScript and comparing times. Use the `Date` object to help.

```
var begTime = new Date(current.data('bgtime')).getTime(),
    endTime = new Date(current.data('endtime')).getTime();

$('#timeToStart').on('change', function() {
    var startTime = new Date($('#timeToStart').val()).getTime();
    sTimeHire = startTime;
});

$('#timeToEnd').on('change', function() {
    var endTime = new Date($('#timeToEnd').val()).getTime();
    eTimeHire = endTime;
});


if (begTime > sTimeHire || endTime < eTimeHire) {
    alert("yayy it works");
}
```

Untested, but this should help you get the idea.

Re: My comment, this isn't strictly a unix timestamp, because its in `ms` and not `s`, but since it's the same everywhere, the same idea applies, *integer time*.

edit: Switched from .now() to .getTime() as suggested.

Comment: May I ask why you're using `now()`? That's defined as a static member of the Date object, not an instance method. Typically one would use `valueOf()` or `getTime()` on a Date object to get the number of milliseconds since the epoch.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I'm getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value).now is not a function